# Remove qualifying lines of text from string including its leading newline or trailing newline, but not both

Tags: regex, pcre2

In the following regex:

```
EXCLUDE this entire line
include this line
and this as single match
and EXCLUDE this line
```

I want to return a single match consisting for two lines:

```
include this line
and this as single match
```

I want to use `EXCLUDE` as string identifying that the entire line should not be included.

edit:
if I can get just the first match up to the line with "EXCLUDE" (or end of document whichever happens first), that would work too

Comment: Please add a tag that identifies the language you are using as different languages have regex engines with different features.

Comment: Suppose the line `"First include this line"` were added before the first line in your example and `"Lastly include this line"` were added after the last line in the example. What would be you desired result?

Comment: yeah, any line(s) that don't contain EXCLUDE should be included, if they are consecutive, it should be a single match. I've been trying different things for 2 days, not sure if it's possible at all.

Comment: if I can get just the first match up to the line with "EXCLUDE" (or end of document), that would work too

Comment: This question differs from the earlier one cited as the basis for closing the question. I initially posted an answer with a regex that matched lines that didn't include the specified word and was quickly admonished, reminded that the OP stated, "I want to return a single match consisting for two lines:.."`. I've voted to reopen. Interesting, my vote reopened the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pcre you can use `\K` to fotget what is matched so far, and first match the line containing exclude:

```
^.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*\K(?:\R(?!.*\bEXCLUDE\b).*)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/458Lhs/1)

If you want to match all lines that do not contain exclude, with consecutive lines:

```
(?:(?:^|\R)(?!.*\bEXCLUDE\b).*)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7V8EwI/1)

Or using a skip fail approach:

```
^.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*\R(*SKIP)(*F)|.+(?:\R(?!.*\bEXCLUDE\b).*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YSRUn0/1)

Comment: Very nice solution! Great for the `\K` and `\R`. It just needs a correction to work if there's a line without the `EXCLUDE` word at the begining: https://regex101.com/r/tszZLF/1

Comment: @PatrickJanser Thank for your comment, in that case I have added 2 pattern that will match those lines.

Comment: I can't tell from the wording of the question if the string necessarily contains a line that contains `"EXCLUDE"`. If there were not such a line the entire string presumably would be returned. You have a typo at `answer[29]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can split the string on matches of the regular expression

```
^.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*\R
```

with global and multiline flags set.

In Ruby, for example, if the variable `str` held the string

```
Firstly include this line
EXCLUDE this entire line
include this line
and this as single match
and EXCLUDE this line
Lastly include this line
```

then the method [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split) could be used to produce an array containing three strings.

```
str.split(/^.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*\R/)
  #=> ["Firstly include this line",
  #    "include this line\nand this as single match",
  #    "Lastly include this line"]
```

Many languages have a method or function that is comparable to Ruby's  `split`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2WdJg/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^        # match the beginning of a line
.*       # match zero or more characters other than line
         # terminators, as many as possible
\b       # match word boundary
EXCLUDE  # match literal
\b       # match word boundary
.*       # match zero or more characters other than line
         # terminators, as many as possible
\R       # match line terminator
```

Comment: Oh, we came out to the same answer! Nice explanation! I also think that splitting is easier than doing it with the opposite matching pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You could also match the lines with the `EXCLUDE` and use it to split your text into blocks of what you are looking for:

```php
<?php

$input = 'First include this line
EXCLUDE this entire line
include this line
and this as single match
and EXCLUDE this line
Lastly include this line';

// ^ matches the beginning of a line.
// .* matches anything (except new lines) zero or multiple times.
// \b matches a word boundary (to avoid matching NOEXCLUDE).
// $ matches the end of a line.
$pattern = '/^.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*$/m';

// Split the text with all lines containing the EXCLUDE word.
$desired_blocks = preg_split($pattern, $input);

// Get rid of the new lines around the matched blocks.
array_walk(
    $desired_blocks,
    function (&$block) {
        // \R matches any Unicode newline sequence.
        // ^ matches the beginning of the string.
        // $ matches the end of the string.
        // | = or
        $block = preg_replace('/^\R+|\R+$/', '', $block);
    }
);

var_export($desired_blocks);
```

Demo here: https://onlinephp.io/c/4216a

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'First include this line',
  1 => 'include this line
and this as single match',
  2 => 'Lastly include this line',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a replacement pattern which doesn't require repeating the search word twice in the pattern, use [a conditional expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).  If a leading newline is found, don't match the trailing newline.  If no leading newline is found, then make the trailing newline optional.

Code: ([Demo with a battery of tests](https://3v4l.org/4kqsD))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
EXCLUDE this entire line
include this line
even this to EXCLUDE
and EXCLUDE this
and this as single match
and EXCLUDE this line
TEXT;

echo preg_replace('/(\R)?.*\bEXCLUDE\b.*(?(1)|\R?)/', '', $text);
```